# Why do I need braces in the following perl one liner?

Tags: perl

I saw a perl one liner to generate some random string of 8 chars:

`perl -le 'print map { ("a".."z")[rand 26] } 1..5'`

but this does not work without the `{}` for map. Why is that?

Comment: What exactly was the code that did not work?  It can be done without `{}`.

Comment: @aschepler: Yes, but if you removed the braces, then you need to add a comma between the block and the list.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [`perldoc -f map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html).  `map` has two forms: `map({block} @array)` and `map(expression, @array)`.  The latter form can be used like so:

```
perl -le 'print map(("a".."z")[rand 26], 1..5)'
perl -le 'print map +("a".."z")[rand 26], 1..5'
```

---

The reason

```
perl -le 'print map ("a".."z")[rand 26], 1..5'
```

doesn't work is because it parses like

```
perl -le 'print(((map("a".."z"))[rand(26)]), 1..5)'
```

In other words, `"a".."z"` become the only arguments of `map`, which is not valid.  This can be disambiguated with an extra set of parentheses or with a unary `+`.

Comment: How did the unary + help there? I see it mentioned in an example in the doc link provided but not sure how it worked. Is it a common thing for avoiding parenthesis in function calls I can google?

Comment: @PalaceChan It is used to separate `map` from the first `(`.  This trick is common Perl usage functions which take multiple arguments -- others include `grep` and `print`.

Comment: It's a disambiguation technique.